# how to run the code inside the subscribe function only once even though I subscribed multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I subscribed multiple time to an observable but I want to run the callback function only once.
is there any rxjs operator to do this?

```
this.store.select(MsnSelectors.getUserWhoTyping).subscribe(uts => {
        if (uts.length > 0) {
          let ut = uts.find(x => x.senderUserName === this.receiver.identifier);
          console.log(ut)
          ut?.isTyping ? this.userTyping = ut : this.userTyping = null;
        }
        else
          this.userTyping = null;
      })`
```

this portion of code is called several times (several subscription),  so when the observable emit new value the code inside the subscribe method execute several times.

Comment: Can you provide some of your code...?

Comment: If you want only single reaction, why did you subscribe multiple times then ?

Answer (score 0):

You could perform your logic within a [`tap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) and then use the [`share`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/share) operator to share your subscription so the logic is only executed once:

```js
uts$ = this.store.select(MsnSelectors.getUserWhoTyping).pipe(
    tap(uts => /* your logic */ ),
    share()
);

subscription1 = this.uts$.subscribe();
subscription2 = this.uts$.subscribe();
subscription3 = this.uts$.subscribe();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var store = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
store.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(uts => {
    if (uts.length > 0) {
      let ut = uts.find(x => x.senderUserName === this.receiver.identifier);
      console.log(ut)
      ut?.isTyping ? this.userTyping = ut : this.userTyping = null;
    }
    else
      this.userTyping = null;
  });
```